A strange functional inequality
Let $f,g \in C([-2,2],\mathbb R_+^*)$ even and concave real functions.

Is it true that
$$
\int_0^1 f\big(\cos(x^{-1})+\sin(x^{-1})\big) \cdot g\big(\cos(x^{-1})-\sin(x^{-1})\big) \mathrm{d}x\\ \leq f(0)\cdot g(1)+g(0)\cdot f(1) -f(1) \cdot g(1)\; ?
$$


I am wondering how this inequality arises.

Are you sure you want $f,g$ defined on $[-2,2]$? We have $|\sin\alpha\pm\cos\alpha|\le\sqrt{2}$.

It seems that this is enough.

@ChristianRemling but not every even concave non-negative on $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ function may be extended to an even concave non-negative on $[-2,2]$ function

Hmm. We have $(\cos t+\sin t)^2+(\cos t-\sin t)^2=2$, thus at least one of numbers $u:=\cos(x^{-1})+\sin(x^{-1})$, $v:=\cos(x^{-1})-\sin(x^{-1})$ have absolute value not less than 1. Since an even concave function decreases on $\mathbb{R}_+$, we have for this number (let it be $v$, for example) $g(v)\leqslant g(1)$, then $f(u)g(v)\leqslant f(0)g(1)\leqslant f(0)g(1)+f(1)g(0)-f(1)g(1)$. It remains to integrate.
